# Number of ways in which 6 rings can be worn on the 4 fingers of one hand

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The way I solved this is -

The 1st finger can have any of the 6 rings, $\therefore 6$ ways

The 2nd finger can have any of the 5 remaining rings, $\therefore 5$ ways

The 3rd finger can have any of the 4 remaining rings, $\therefore 4$ ways

The 4th finger can have any of the 3 remaining rings, $\therefore 3$ ways

$\therefore$ total number of ways = 5*4*3*2 = 120 ways.

But every website I check for the solution, they are different and I'm very confused. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Are the rings distinguishable?  If so, does the order in which they are placed on a finger matter?  Also, is there an implicit assumption that at least one ring must be placed on each finger?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, there are no such restrictions or conditions given

Comment: The question is so vague that it is susceptible to manifold interpretations, so it is no wonder that  different answers are being given !

Answer (score 4):

You can order the $6$ rings in $6! = 720$ ways. Now you have to split the string of $6$ rings into $4$ groups, one for each finger. One way to see how to do this is [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars), you have $6$ stars ($*$, the rings) and $4 - 1 = 3$ bars ($\mid$, separations between groups), this is to select $4 - 1$ positions for the $\mid$ among $6 + 4 - 1$ positions in all. Pulling all together:

$\begin{align}
6! \cdot \binom{6 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = 720 \cdot 84 = 60480
\end{align}$

Comment: @Sidsec9  This solution, which is correct, is based on the assumptions that the rings are distinguishable and that the order in which they are placed on the fingers matters.

Answer (score 0):

See, fixing the 4 fingers and permutation over the rings doesn't work in these cases.
So, just fix the 6 rings
r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6
Now, first ring can be worn in four ways (in either of the 4 fingers) , similarly 2nd ring also in 4 ways..
So total ways are 4×4×4×4×4×4 = 4096
I hope this helps..

Comment: you seems to be assuming the rings are distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

There are simply 4 ways for each of the 6 rings to be placed in the fingers. So, 1 answer is 4^6 = 4096. But this can only be used if the rings are not identical.
If the rings are identical then, stars and bar method is the best. We can place the 6 rings with the 3 bars in a line. Now there are 9C3 ways of arranging the rings. Hence, there are 84 ways of placing the rings if the rings are identify.
Another case is when we are just to use the 4 out of 6 rings each in a finger and the rings are not identical. Here we can use the formula of 6*5*4*3 that is 360.
I hope your confusion is cleared.

Answer (score -1):

See you can choose the fingers in ${5\choose 4}$ ways . and then normal calculations which you have done $=5.6.5.4.3=1800$ hope its clear.

Comment: You misinterpreted the question.  All six rings are worn on four fingers of one hand.

Comment: But hand can be selected in $2$ ways as they are distinct??

Comment: Read the question again.  There are only four fingers available on which to place the rings.

Comment: On one hand is making confusion .